# ErrorException Trying to get property 'name' of non-object \views\navigation-menu.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Please help me to resolve this error,

> ErrorException Trying to get property 'name' of non-object \views\navigation-menu.blade.php)

**livewire\Domaines.php**

```php
public function store()
{
   $this->validate ([
       'nomDomaine' => 'required',
   ]);
   Domaine::updateOrCreate(
       ['id'=> $this->domaine_id],
       [
       'nomDomaine' => $this->nomDomaine,
       ]
   );
   session()->flash('message',
   $this->domaine_id ? 'Domaine mis a jour avec succes' : 'Domaine cree avec succes'
   );
   $this->closeModal();
   $this->resetInputFields();
}

public function edit($id)
{
   $domaine = Domaine::findOrFall($id);
   $this->nomDomaine = $domaine->nomDomaine;
   $this->openModal();
}

public function render()
{
   $this->domaines = Domaine::all();
   return view('livewire.domaines', 
   ['domaines' => Domaine::paginate(6),]);
}
```

**livewire\domaines.blade.php**

```html
@if($isOpen)
    @include('livewire.creer-domaines')
@endif
    <tbody>
        @foreach($domaines as $domaine)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $domaine->nomDomaine }}</td>
                <td>{{ $domaine->descriptionDomaine }}</td>
                <td>   
                    <button wire:click="edit({{ $domaine->id }})>Modifier</button>
                    <button wire:click="delete({{ $domaine->id }})>Supprimer</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

**route\web.php**

```
use App\Http\Livewire\Domaines; 
Route::get('domaine', Domaines::class);
```

Comment: There's no `name` attribute being used here. On what line is it? Is it from your layout that is Auth-protected perhaps?

Comment: Also, this `@include('livewire.creer-domaines')` is not how you render a Livewire component. See https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger. For a proper question here, you'd need a [mcve]. Please, as a new user here, also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @Quirel it is in file ressources/view/navigation-menu.blade.php at page 156